# python 3 adding multiple values under same key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i have a problem with my code, tried looking up how to fix it and tried multiple methods but its just not going

Here is what i got:

```
with open("people-data.txt") as f:

children= {}
for line in f.readlines():
    parent, child = line.split("->")
    children[parent] = child
```

I tried using: `children[parent].append(child)` and other things.

My file looks like this:

```
Mary->Patricia
Mary->Lisa
Patricia->Barbara
```

What I would like is when I use `children[Mary]` I get `['Patricia', 'Lisa']` but what my code does is give my just `'Lisa'` and overrides `'Patricia'`.

Comment: It should be `children[parent] = child`. In your case you would store the key `"parent"` and overwrite it.

Comment: ye sorry, my mistake from copying, let my correct it

Comment: You need to use a defaultdict from collections.

Comment: Of course it overwrites. What else would `children[parent] = child` do? You need to  keep lists in each value of the dict, which can be easily done by using `children = defaultdict(list)` and `children[parent].append(child)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using: `children[parent].append(child)`

That will work as long as you are using lists for your dictionary-values.

The easiest fix to achieve that would be to make children a `defaultdict`, i.e.

```
from collections import defaultdict
children = defaultdict(list)
```

and then use

```
children[parent].append(child)
```

in your code.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> children = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> children['Peter'].append('Bob')
>>> children['Peter'].append('Alice')
>>> children['Mary'].append('Joe')
>>> 
>>> children
defaultdict(list, {'Mary': ['Joe'], 'Peter': ['Bob', 'Alice']})
```

Comment: Yes, and don't forget: `children[parent].append(child)` for a complete solution.

Comment: Thank you, it is now creating what i wanted, but the problem is that when i call children("Mary") i get that it is not callable, i need the values to work with later on

Comment: @DávidKačmar `children['Mary']`.

Comment: Thank you!!!! i love you guys!! or girls :D saved my day :D thanks alot